# Simple Continuous Function Issue

Tags: calculus, functions

During my review, I've come across a problem that involves determining whether $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x-y}$ is continuous in a rectangular region of the x-y plane with the point $(2,2)$ at its center. I've said yes, based on the notion that a function is continuous if it exists in its domain, and $f(2,2) = \sqrt{2-2}$ is just $0$. Apparently, however, it isn't. I'm a bit rusty with continuity, but nothing I've tried searching has made me understand why this isn't continuous. If anyone could provide even a basic explanation, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity has to do with the behavior of a function near a point, not just at the point itself. It's true that $f(2,2) = 0$ is defined, but for any open set containing $(2,2)$, there are points $(x,y)$ for which $y > x$, i.e. $x - y < 0$ so $f$ is undefined. Of course, if you restrict to the set $y \leq x$, then $f$ is defined and continuous.